# Google Sheets script error "Unreachable Service: mirror"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script in Google Sheets where I literally can't execute anything. For example:

```
    function onOpen(e) {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or SpreadsheetApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu("Ampion Sheet Control")
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem("Ampion Sheet Control Wizard", "showSidebarIntro")
        .addToUi();
    }
```

I just get the error:

> Unreachable Service: mirror

Comment: It runs for me.

Comment: Could you provide more context? Can you reproduce this behaviour in other scripts and with other accounts? I can run the code you shared with any problem.

Comment: Today, I got the same issue while using the Google Classroom API. I was told to create an issue in the issueTracker, and in fact the issue was already open: "Unable to reach script server" in https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/153514647. Put your comment there with a description of the problem, so they can address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the question has a noticeable answer:

There is an issue [submitted](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/153514647) to the issue tracker that is as of now not yet resolved (or confirmed as an actual bug for that matter). Since `mirror` is the id (note - not identifier, the Id) of the [advanced Mirror service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/mirror), make sure that the service is turned off:

[image]

And that there is no corresponding dependency in the `appscript.json` manifest file:

```
{
 "userSymbol": "Mirror",
 "serviceId": "mirror",
 "version": "v1"
}
```

If after doing this (or if you need access to Mirror) the issue is unresolved, please star the issue on the tracker and add info about your case in the comments to the issue.