# Google Apps Script: "Unreachable Service: mirror" error

Tags: google-apps-script

Some months ago (while Apps Script was using the Rhino runtime) I wrote a script using the Google Classroom API. All the functions in the script always worked fine. When in February Google changed to the Chrome V8 runtime, I migrated my script and it continued working fine.

Today, when I try to run any of the functions of this script, I get an "Unreachable Service: mirror" error. No matter the function called.

Other person reported 9 days ago a similar error ([googlesheets script error “Unreachable Service: mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493247/googlesheets-script-error-unreachable-service-mirror)).

Does anybody know what this error could mean?

Comment: Create a issue in the tracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, an issue is open for this problem: "Unable to reach script server" in issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/153514647. I have put there my problem.

Comment: That issue is closed. Consider creating a new issue. Also , star the issue and then comment.

Comment: Are you a G Suite user?

Comment: Sure, I am a G Suite user with a corporate account.

Comment: Update: now when I try to modify any part of the script and save it I get the message "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.". So, after all, it could be a server error from Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493247/google-sheets-script-error-unreachable-service-mirror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is facing the same issue:

This looks like a bug and it has been reported in Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/153514647). You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug.